# JSONP adapter Phonegap project not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jsonp

I am using the sample code (slightly modified) to implement a JSONP adapter found here: http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/04/building-pluggable-and-mock-data-adapters-for-web-and-phonegap-applications/

My modified in-memory adapter works, but when I try to change from using the mock data, to a JSONP data object from a remote server, it doesn't work.  Below is my memory adapter:

```
var JSONPAdapter = function() {

this.initialize = function(data) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    url = data;
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise();
}

this.findById = function(id) {
    return $.ajax({url: url + "/" + id, dataType: "jsonp"});
}

this.findByName = function(searchKey) {
    return $.ajax(
        {
            url: url + "?Name=" + searchKey,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) { },
            error: function (XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("error: " + errorThrown + '\nurl: ' + url + "?Name=" + searchKey);
        }
    });
}

this.getAll = function getAll() {
    return $.ajax({ url: url, dataType: "jsonp" });
}

var url;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the /callback=? appended to the end of the url. This is taken care of automatically because the dataType is set to 'jsonp'.

Comment: Closer, but now I'm getting undefined in my phonegap project as the JSONP objects returned.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your help.  I decided to do the call inside the findByName function, which appears to fire correctly, only it returns undefined data.  It does know how many objects are in the undefined data (3).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think the problem you're now seeing is due to the fact you are returning the whole $.ajax(...) object as opposed to just returning the data. e.g `success: function (data) { return data; }`

Comment: You might be on to something.  One interesting thing is that in the callback function, if I do an alert with JSON.stringify(data) I can see all the data correctly!

Comment: when you're returning the JSON data, like in my comment above - it will be the actual JSON object you're returning, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to the scope of your JSONData variable.
It is not initialised correctly if there is an error within the getJSONData() call. Try declaring the JSONData variable before the function is defined.

Comment: I'm sorry the JSONData variable is not used, it is the employees variable that contains the data.  I removed the unused function from the original post to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok - added another answer, unless I've missed something else.